# Why is my lambda function not working as expected?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm getting this error from lambda: `errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"Error: Unable to stringify response body`

I'm trying to trigger my lambda from an upload in s3 (this part is working) and then that should post something into dynamoDB

here is my lambda in full

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var S3 = require('aws-sdk/clients/s3');

const s3 = new AWS.S3()
var DynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
    var bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    var json_file_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    var params = {
      Bucket: bucket, 
      Key: json_file_name
     };

    const data = await s3.getObject(params).promise();

    const dataToDb = data.Body.toString('utf-8');

    console.log(dataToDb, 'TESTING ====')

    var dbparams = {
        TableName: "MY-TABLE-NAME",
        Item: dataToDb, 
    };

    const putIntoDB = await DynamoDB.put(dbparams, function (err) {
         if (err) {
             console.log(err, 'er===');
         }
        else {
            console.log(dbparams, 'db====')
        }
    });

    return putIntoDB
};
```

the data that is coming from s3 is just a simple json object with 4 keys so nothing big at all.
my table consists of just a primary key called `user_id` and that field IS in my json object that comes back from S3 so no idea why this isn't working?

Comment: **"Lambda error: Unable to stringify response body"** would be a much much better and search engine friendly title.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`DynamoDB.put` is a callback and you are trying to `await` on it, so this will never work. You should chain the `.promise()` method just like you did with your `s3.getObject` call.

`await DynamoDB.put(dbparams).promise()`

If you want to handle errors, just wrap it in a `try/catch` block:

```
try {
    await DynamoDB.put(dbparams).promise()
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
}
```

On top of that, you also need to feed the `Item` attribute of your DynamoDB call with a JSON object, not with a string.

I am not sure what you get from s3, but converting it to a JSON object by using `JSON.parse(dataToDb`) should do the trick given the data is a valid JSON object.

Comment: ok when I try that I'm getting this: ` { TableName: 'richjmatt-test-ddb', Item: '{\n "name": "Rich",\n "age": 26,\n "city": "London",\n "user_id": "1"\n}\n' } ` how can I remove these newlines? it's saying I'm missing the key "user_id" but clearly it is there...

Comment: because `item` is a String and not a JSON object. You converted it to a String yourself. I am not sure what you get back from s3, but if the content itself is not a JSON, just run `JSON.parse(dataToDb`) and that should work

Comment: what. the. flip. I swear i tried that. anyway it worked! thanks man

Comment: No problem. I also edited my answer to reflect the JSON part which I completely overlooked in my initial answer.

Comment: @ThalesMinussi Using `async-await` promises in themselves right? Then what difference does it make to add `promise()` explicitly to the dynamoDb.put() or if using Aurora RDS.executeStatement()? Can you help explain this bit?

Comment: @bubble-cord that's because without the .promise() call, you are invoking the SDK's callback functions instead of promises, which means that awaiting on callbacks wouldn't have any effect

Comment: @ThalesMinussi. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 encoding is usually `utf8` when used as an argument in node. I would start there.

Comment: `'utf8'` and `'utf-8'`are both valid and equivalent here.